# can some one help me on the test class,i wrote it but it will give 0% code coverage

Tags: unit-test

```
public class KAddNoteControllers {
   public boolean displayPopup {get; set;}
   public ApexPages.StandardController nad;
   public KAddNoteControllers(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
   }
   public pagereference closePopup() {
   this.nad.save();
       PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/KDetailpage');
       pageref.setRedirect(true);
       return pageref;
   }

   public void showPopup() {
       displayPopup = true;
   }

    public K_Document__c objNote{get;set;}
    String kId='';
    public KAddNoteControllers(){
        objNote = new K_Document__c();
        kId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    }
    public void save(){
    Datetime yourDate = Datetime.now();
    String dateOutput = yourDate.format('MM/dd/yyyy  h:mm a');
        K_Document__c doc = [Select Id, note__c from K_Document__c where id=:kId];
        if(objNote.note__c <> null){ //format('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'
            String note = '<B>' + UserInfo.getName() + '</B>'+ '&nbsp&nbsp' + '<B>'+  yourDate.format('MM/dd/yyyy  h:mm a') + '</B>' ;
            note += '<BR/>' + objNote.note__c;
            doc.note__c = note + '<BR/><BR/>' + common.NVL(doc.note__c);

            update doc;


        }
    }
}
```

**and my test class is ---**

```
@isTest//(SeeAllData=true)
private class test_KAddNoteControllers {
  static testMethod void test_KAddNoteControllers1()
  {
      //page reference
   K_Document__c obj=new K_Document__c ();
   PageReference pageRef = Page.KAddNote;
    System.assertNotEquals(null,pageRef);
    System.assertEquals('/apex/KDetailpage',pageRef.getUrl());
    Map<String,String> pageParameters = pageRef.getParameters();
    System.assertEquals(1,pageParameters.values().size());
    System.assertEquals('recordId',pageParameters.get('id'));
  }
  private static testMethod void showpopup()
    {

    }
  private static testMethod void test_KAddNoteControllers2()
  { //add record
      K_Document__c k1=new K_Document__c();
      k1.id='12345';
      k1.note__c='abcde';
      insert k1;
    }  
    //for constructotr
    private static testMethod void test_KAddNoteControllers3()
    {
      K_Document__c k1=new K_Document__c();
       ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(k1);
       KHeaderController controller = new KHeaderController(sc);
      }
    private static testMethod void save()
    {

    }
      }
```

Please some one help me on this.please.

Comment: Hi @Mona.sdfc. welcome to SFSE! Your question is asking for other people to write code for you, without presenting a real question or issue. SFSE is a Q&A forum where we look to help each other by asking and answering questions that are real problems or errors. Posting requests to write code for you will get closed. If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, i'm confident you'll find plenty of people willing to assist you.

Answer (score 2):

You never actually do anything with your class. All you are doing in your test is creating a K_Document__c but never actually use it along with the class (unless a trigger is supposed to execute your class but it looks like a VF controller so here is a start:

```
static testMethod void test_KAddNoteControllers1()
  {
      //page reference
   K_Document__c obj=new K_Document__c ();
   PageReference pageRef = Page.KAddNote;
    //These asserts are meaningless unless you are just doing them for the sake of it.
    //System.assertNotEquals(null,pageRef);
    //System.assertEquals('/apex/KDetailpage',pageRef.getUrl());

    //Map<String,String> pageParameters = pageRef.getParameters();
    //System.assertEquals(1,pageParameters.values().size());
    //System.assertEquals('recordId',pageParameters.get('id'));

    //Create an instance of a standard controller for the obj you created
    ApexPages.standardController stdcon = New ApexPages.StandardController(obj);
    //Now instantiate your class
    //Although this will do nothing as the constructor is empty but for the sake of completeness
    KAddNoteControllers con = New KAddNoteControllers(stdcon);

    //You need to set the page reference as you are grabbing parameters from he URL
    pageRef.getParameters().put('id',obj.id);
    test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

    //Now an example that will test one of your methods in the class
    con.objNote.Note__c = 'Test 1234';
    Pagereference result = con.closePopup();
    //Assert the correct page reference was returned
    system.assertEquals(true,result.getURL().contains('/apex/KDetailpage');

    //Get the record and assert the note was saved
    obj = [Select note__c From k_document__c Where ID = :obj.id];
    system.assertEquals('Test 1234',obj.note__c);

  }
```

**Note** This answer does not address the actual quality of your controller which could you a lot of work....**This test will not pass as you will be attempting to use NAD in your class and it is null so it should throw a DNO not to mention the way you have done it will not use the save method in your class**